# Pentaho connection issue

Tags: sql-server

I installed MS SQL Server 2008 R2 on my laptop, just to practice SQL and it is running on localhost. I also downloaded Pentaho to learn a BI tools. The problem is I have been getting the below error for a week or so and cannot seem to find a solution.

```
Error connecting to database [test] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver)
Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver)
Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
```

I have tried every possible login combination and also installed the necessary Java drives.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your code for connecting?

Comment: There is no code for connection, you just choose the connection type in Pentaho and put your credentials.

Comment: If you log in using _SQL Server Management Studio_ using identical details does it work? Are you using windows or SQL Authentication? Are you using a named instance? Giving us your connection details will shed some light on this for us. Keep in mind that no matter how you connect, behind the scenes a connection string is used (in your case a JDBC connection string)

Answer (score 2):

At the first, you check sql server is listening on default port, sometimes isn´t take default port(antivirus,firewal, anyway).

1. Check the PID of SQL server service
2. type "netstat -a -n -o" command on console
3. search your PID on it and get your port where your sqlserver is listening

[image]

[image]